# Accessing a USB device from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: usb, activex

I would like my web application (which runs on intranet only) to be able to interface with a USB finger print device, that captures the fingerprint of a user through an enrollment web application

I tried googling, but it seems that the only viable way is Active X, which, from what I've read, is supported on IE only.

Is there a solution/work around/crude hack, that allows me to interface with a USB device, that works across all browsers?

I can accept the following conditions:

1. prompting to install 3rd party files/active x/etc
2. security doesn't concern me as this is used on intranet only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about writing a browser plugin? For example, Chrome developer documentation has information on [Accessing Hardware Devices](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_hardware.html), with an API for specifically accessing USB devices.

You could then use a [Content Script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to interact with your page, for example, replacing an `<input type="fingerprint" />` element with your fingerprint scanning UI (eg. show an image of scanned print). I don't know the details of the UX you're trying to achieve so it's hard to say.

Another way would be to generate a windows.fingerprintScanned event (which you'd also do with a Content script and message passing), which you could then handle in your regular javascript page code from the app server.

---

The downside to the browser extension is that it's more specialized: if you want a Firefox or IE plugin, you'd have to write for those specifically.  Just putting this out as an alternative to Flash/Silverlight/Java (which are cross-browser but have their own downsides).

Answer (score 1):

How about a [Silverlight trusted application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

Edit- Also, as a side note, I believe security should always be a concern, because of things like pivot attacks and social engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Hack I don't know, but you can do your web app send something to a queue and install a client that read the data from this queue. You understand?